# Simulate click on same div by class names

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have five boxes with the same class name but some `<div>`s has another class too.
Example:

```
<div class="test one"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test two"></div>
<div class="test three"></div>
<div class="test five"></div>
```

I use this code for clicking on boxes with `.test` class but it clicks on all boxes:

```
$('.test').click();
```

How can I simulate click on the second `<div>` that *only* has `.test` class name, and not more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a CSS attribute selector to select elements with ***only one*** class:

```
$('[class="test"]').click();
```

```js
$('[class="test"]').click(function() {
  $(this).css('background', 'blue');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test one">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
<div class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
<div class="test two">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
<div class="test three">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
<div class="test five">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could return all classes with `attr` and check length

```js
$('.test').click(function() {
  var c = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').length;
  if (c == 1) {
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test one">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
<div class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
<div class="test two">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
<div class="test three">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
<div class="test five">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
```

If you always want to target div with only `test` class no matter which one you click you can do this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/506/)

Comment: This answer is *way* more complicated than using an attribute selector.